2000 limit in typescript flow analysis and geting error "The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis"
I'm using tsc4.9 and geting error "The containing function or module body is too large for control flow analysis". I found typescript has a limit of 2000 in flow analysis. Is it only to avoid stack ovarflow? And why use 2000 not 3000 or 4000?
                if (flowDepth === 2000) {
                    // We have made 2000 recursive invocations. To avoid overflowing the call stack we report an error
                    // and disable further control flow analysis in the containing function or module body.
                    tracing?.instant(tracing.Phase.CheckTypes, "getTypeAtFlowNode_DepthLimit", { flowId: flow.id });
                    flowAnalysisDisabled = true;
                    reportFlowControlError(reference);
                    return errorType;
                }

Why use 2000 but not 3000 or 4000 here?
Can I change this limit to 3000,4000 or much more like 100000?

"And why use 2000 not 3000 or 4000?" The comment explains why. I'm not sure anyone here will be able to provide much more than that. I would recommend you use smaller functions.

You can flip this question on its head and just ask, why not use 2000? It's a reasonably large limit which probably fits most workflows

It was like 2500 before, it blew the stack in ms/TS#26031, this was reduced to 2000 in ms/TS#26585. If you make it bigger in a forked version of the compiler you might not hit the problem, but it's there for that reason. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?
